# How to preserve a Guid when importing it to Mongo from a CSV file?

Tags: mongodb, etl, mongoimport

I need to import records from a CSV file into a MongoDb collection.  I'm currently using [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) as the tool.

The "_id" field is supposed to have the format UUID("**[UserGuid]**") where **[UserGuid]** is a placehoder for a Guid generated by a C# application [using Guid.NewGuid()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-5.0).

So one example of a desired result for this field (after the import) would be:

> `"_id" : UUID("9067d1bd-df31-4264-aa50-7a7639687e91")`

The above is precisely how the field should appear when viewing it from a MongoDb client, with the double quotes appearing around the Guid.

The problem is that, after the import, the value where **[UserGuid]** should be has been transformed to some other value.  If I keep trying to import the guid shown above, it's always converted to

> `"_id" : UUID("39303637-6431-6264-2d64-6633312d3432")`

How can I import the values from the CSV file so that the Guid value specified in the CSV is preserved and not transformed?

Comment: Where do you display your results? Are you talking about the representation of your data via some GUI? It seems like your data is ok but your GUI shows to you formatted ID. Look at your data via mongo client.

Comment: I'm looking at the data via a database management tool like Robo 3T/ Studio 3T / MongoDb Compass. Also when I use the import tool, my csv column with the id value is actually named: "_id" so this will automatically set it as the identity (_id) field.  Then I specify that it should have the UUID data type.

Comment: So, is the problem related only to quotes differences?

Comment: No, the problem is that the guid is being changed.  To refer back to my example: the guid in the csv file is 9067d1bd-df31-4264-aa50-7a7639687e91, but when I import it, it gets transformed to 39303637-6431-6264-2d64-6633312d3432.  I would like the value of 9067d1bd-df31-4264-aa50-7a7639687e91 to be stored in the database, without being transformed.